# Overlapping flags in Highstock

Tags: highcharts, overlap

I'm designing a chart with `Highstock`, which display a series with some flags on it.

Depending of my data, flags can be close enough so they overlap. It can give something like this :
[image]

Is there a way to throw to the front of the chart, with `zIndex` or something like this?

**UPDATE**

All these flags belong to a series (different from the spline).

This series is build like this :

```
var flagsNews = {
    type : 'flags',
    data : aFlags,
    onSeries : 'myLineSeries',
    shape: 'squarepin'          
};
```

each element of `aFlags` is pushed like this :

```
aFlags.push({
    x : (new Date(newsData['date_publication']).getTime()),
    title : 'a title', 
    text : 'a text', 
    id : 'flagID',
    events : {
       mouseOver : function(){
           //some stuff      
       },
       mouseOut : function(){
           //some stuff    
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "throw to the front of the chart"? They can't both be on top. But I guess you would like to move the flags or something, so they don't overlap?

Comment: What I really mean by "throw to the front of the chart" is to perform an update within mouseOver, or with another event on my page with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In general this solution is not supported, but you adapt this solution http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/6/.

```
events: {
                load: function() {
                    StaggerDataLabels(this.series);
                },
                redraw: function() {
                    var series = this.series;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        StaggerDataLabels(series);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },
```

Comment: I'm using the series type `flags` from `Highstock`, no the data labels. I've updated my question.

Comment: In the flags this solutions is not available.